# Convert python list of lists into dictionary format

Tags: python-2.7

I have the following python list of lists:

```
[[14.76, u'2017-10-11T06:00:00Z'], [14.75, u'2017-10-11T07:00:00Z'], [14.21, u'2017-10-11T08:00:00Z']]
```

And I need to get it into a dictionary:

```
{'2017-10-11T06:00:00Z' : 14.76, '2017-10-11T07:00:00Z':14.75, '2017-10-11T08:00:00Z': 14.21}
```

Comment: so, you forgot to *ask a question*. (A question is a sentence that rightfully ends in "?") What is it? Have you read the official python documentation on the dictionary type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's pretty simple. The `dict` constructor already accepts an iterable of two-element-iterables. The only extra difficulty here is that your keys and values are in reverse order.

```
>>> mylist = [[14.76, u'2017-10-11T06:00:00Z'], [14.75, u'2017-10-11T07:00:00Z'], [14.21, u'2017-10-11T08:00:00Z']]
>>> dict(map(reversed, mylist))
{u'2017-10-11T07:00:00Z': 14.75, u'2017-10-11T06:00:00Z': 14.76, u'2017-10-11T08:00:00Z': 14.21}*
```

Answer (score 2):

```
d = dict()
for v, k in l:
    d[k] = v
```

l - initial list